# How are increases calculated when leveling up?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

At first it seemed obvious to me but now I'm beginning to question it seeing as how I can't find anything explicit in the RAW.  This is hard to phrase but I'll do my best.

The question is regarding Ability Modifiers, Spells per day, BAB, fort. will and ref. saves, and experience totals.

Basically my question is, when looking at the tables after leveling up, are the numbers by the level the new total or what I'm adding to my current number.  For example;

I level up from level 1 to 2 as a [Barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian).  Is my BAB going from +1 to +2 or is it now +3 because it was 1 and now I'm adding 2?

I'm also wondering the same principle for [experience](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement).  In a Medium paced game, the barbarian would reach level 2 at 2,000 and level 3 at 5,000.  Does that mean that once he is level 2 he only needs 3,000 more or does he need the another 5,000 putting him at a 7,000 total?

Sorry if this seems ridiculous but the more I look at it the more it makes me wonder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When referring to a table that describes what bonuses you get at a particular level, each level does not stack with the ones before it.  This applies to anything numeric: spells per day, save, BAB, experience, etc.

For example, Barbarians get +1 to their BAB each level.  At level 5, they have a total of +5 BAB, which is what is listed on the table.

For experience, the listed numbers are the *total* number of experience points you need to gain that level.  For example, a character with 2000 XP is level 2.  They need to gain 3000 more XP to reach level 3, when their total would be 5000.

Comment: That's what I figured and I'm guessing that applies to most tables like spells per day as well.  Just wanted to make sure because that would surely be quite a difference if it were the other way around.  Thanks!